# Simple event chaining in Actionscript. How can I force a display refresh?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I'm attempting to take a process that previously ran multiple remote object calls in parallel and make them run in serial.

I know it's a hackish approach (bandaid!), but so far my approach has been to take this for-loop that started each parallel request:

**(original code)**

```
for (i = 0; i < _processQ.length; i++){
 fObj = _processQ.getItemAt(i);
 f = fObj.Name;
 fObj.Progress = "Processing..."; 
 ro.process(gameid,f);
}
```

and change it to this:

**(new code)**

```
for (i = 0; i < _processQ.length; i++){
 fObj = _processQ.getItemAt(i);
 f = fObj.Name;
 fObj.Progress = "Processing..."; 
 ro.process(gameid,f);

 //pause this loop until a result is returned from the request that was just made.
 _pause_queue = true;
 while(_pause_queue){
  //do nothing
 }
}
```

Where `_pause_queue` is a private global boolean for the class. In the fault-handler and response-handler functions, it is set back to false, so that the infinite where-loop is released and the for loop will continue.

This is functional, but the UI only updates after the while-loop ends, which causes the negative side effect that it looks like the application is hung while waiting for a response.

Is there something I can put inside the while loop to allow flash to update the display? In VB (ugh!) I would use `DoEvents`, but I don't know of an equivalent for Actionscript.

Alternately, is there a way to add a ***simple*** queueing system short of completely rewriting the application? This is legacy code and I'm on a tight deadline so I'd like to modify it as little as possible. (Otherwise I would rewrite it from the ground up and use Swiz to get the Event Chaining.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Alternately, is there a way to add a
>   simple queueing system short of
>   completely rewriting the application?

Yes, you can use an array.  It looks like you may already have one, with the _processQ variable.  I might try something like this:

```
// A process queue item method
protected function processItemInQueue():Void{
 if(_processQ.length > 0){
  fObj = _processQ.pop();
  f = fObj.Name;
  fObj.Progress = "Processing..."; 
  ro.process(gameid,f);
 }
}
```

Then in your remote Object result handler:

```
protected function roResultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void{
 // process results

 // process next item in queue
 processItemInQueue();
}
```

Comment: +1.  This is much better than any type of while loop... embrace the asynchronicity of Flex.  It takes time to love it, but it really is superior... If I knew the number of items, I might consider writing some fluent async function chaining such that you could do something like this:  `executeProcess(proc1, handler1).executeProcess(proc2, handler2).executeProcess(proc3, handler3).Go()`  It would do the same stuff under the hood, but it would be more expressive.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to do something similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

ActionScript is single threaded so a while (true) loop would indeed hang forever. What you might want to consider is using a Timer class to fire off events regularly or add an event listener to ENTER_FRAME (flash player thinks in the fps domain) which is fired at the start of each frame.

Looking at your code, unless ro.process() is a remote IO operation (fetching a web page or making a web service call), they would hang the UI while they do their work. You might want to split up the work and fire them every frame rather than all at once. You should also learn how to use EventDispatcher logic to listen to when they finish or faults instead of setting a global variable and loop.

Comment: -1 The Flash Player isn't single threaded.  If it were, he'd never be able to fire off multiple remote requests in parallel; he'd have to wait for one to finish before he could fire off the second.  It is true to say that the Flash Player does not offer an API for programmers to create individual threads

Comment: I didn't mean the player itself, I should say ActionScript.

Please read http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/threads_in_actionscript_3.html

"Because Actionscript is single-threaded, if you spend lots of time doing heavy computation, the UI cannot be updated while you’re doing that computation so your application appears stuck or effects don’t run smoothly."

Comment: I also mentioned that flex does allow non-blocking remote I/O in my original answer.

Comment: +1 for clarifying your post and linking to Alex's blog post.  I don't think I had seen that before.

Comment: For what it's worth, RO is a remote object, so yes, `ro.process()` is a remote IO operation. It doesn't hang the UI, the while-loop does.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with clement -- why not make it all some event rather than trying to do everything in a single loop?

```
function outerFunction() {
    var queue = new SomeAsyncProcessor();

    for (i = 0; i < _processQ.length; i++){
        queue.addProcess(_processQ.getItemAt(i));
    }

    queue.addEventListener('complete', handleProcess);
    queue.start();

    game.pause();
}

function handleProcess(event) {

    var processor   = event.currentTarget as SomeAsyncProcessor();
    process.removeEventListener('complete', unpause);

    game.unpause();
}
```

For a priorityqueue -- you could use this:

http://www.polygonal.de/legacy/as3ds/doc/de/polygonal/ds/PriorityQueue.html

Shouldn't be too much time to write one as well, mainly just wrapping what you have currently into one big event dispatcher (as long as your current processors already dispatch events).

Comment: I like the idea of using a queue as the solution, but I don't understand how your code actually accomplishes that.